# Particle movement in three Dimensions

Tags: 3d, movement, particles, perlin-noise, three.js

I have created a particle system which movement is controlled by a flow field over perlin noise - [Available here](http://marky.pl/vu/vf/).

I would be very thankful for any ideas and tips how to control their movement on the Z-plane (noise is 3d), as my 3d knowledge is still very poor.

How to describe the movement controlled by noise value in the third dimension?
I guess the displacement has to be described by a vector directing the movement and added to current possition, but how to determine the z component?

3d example video is available [here](https://vimeo.com/29082224)

Comment: what should I answer insteal of, "proceed with z analogous to x and y". If you have a 3d Perlin as you mentionend, use that z component from your noise function in the same way as you used your x and y components.

Comment: For particle flows, you may also be interested in Curl Noise http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~rbridson/docs/bridson-siggraph2007-curlnoise.pdf - this generates a divergence-free vector field analogous to turbulence in fluids with low compressibility (like water), which reduces the tendency of particles to clump-together into threads as shown in your demo.

Comment: @mjanisz1: wow, your demo looks much cooler now!

Comment: @DMGregory Do you happen to have some algorithm implementation of this Curl noise? It looks neat, but I don't feel like coding it myself :-]

Comment: @lot thanks, still trying to tweak it a bit. Now im struggling how to move it to the gpu to make more particles

Comment: Nope, sorry. I plan to code one up if I'm ever writing a particle system, but I haven't had such a need as of yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you always set z portion of each particle position to 0. Same thing that you've done for x and y do now for z and you are all set, I guess. That means most of all - create third instance of SimplexNoise and use it to calcualte z position in your animation() function.

Then add something like FirstPersonControls.js so viewer can actually enjoy third dimension.